# Check if element is occurring very first time in python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with values occurring multiple times. I want to loop over the list and check if value is occurring very first time.

For eg: Let's say I have a one list like ,

L = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','e','e','e'.......]

Now, at every first occurrence of element, I want to perform some set of tasks.

How to get the first occurrence of element?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You mean you want the **index** of the first occurrence?

Comment: If I can get index, then also it's fine, main objective is to check when element occurs at first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `set` to check if you had processed that item already:

```
visited = set()
L = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','e','e','e'.......] 
for e in L:
    if e not in visited:
        visited.add(e)
        # process first time tasks
    else:
        # process not first time tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique_everseen` from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes).

This function returns a generator which yield only the first occurence of an element.

### Code

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

### Example

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

for x in unique_everseen(lst):
    print(x) # Do something with the element
```

### Output

```
a
b
c
```

The function `unique_everseen` also allows to pass a `key` for comparison of elements. This is useful in many cases, by example if you also need to know the position of each first occurence.

### Example

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

for i, x in unique_everseen(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(i, x)
```

### Output

```
0 a
2 b
3 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using that?

```
L = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','e','e','e'.......] 
for idxL, L_idx in enumerate(L):
    if (L.index(L_idx) == idxL):
        print("This is first occurence")
```

For very long lists, it is less efficient than building a set prior to the loop, but seems more direct to write.